# Winter Release '20 - Lead Conversion Account Trigger Error

Tags: trigger, error, financial-services-cloud, winter20

I just wanted to post this somewhere so that others are aware. The Salesforce Winter '20 release for Financial Services Cloud comes with an error attached to  the Account-Account Relationship (AAR) object. After the release, when you try to add a record to the AAR object it throws the error below. The release contained a new field named "Association Type" for the AAR object that is referenced in the AccountAccountRelationTrigger within the managed package.

Error Message:

System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, You don't have the level of access required to complete this action. Please contact your administrator for help.: []

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give Edit permission to the Association Type field for users that need to add relationship (AAR) records.